# How to style the dropdown UI in the basic html select element in React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

```
      <select className="option-select">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="opel">Opel</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
```

Here is how the basic select is defined. How to target the dropdown list UI? For example, changing the default background of the dropdown.

EDIT:

I find that it does work in Chrome if I target the `<option>` element. But on firefox, it does not work.

Comment: You're pretty limited on the styling that you can apply to a `<select>` because its rendering is very much driven by the host OS.  Your best bet is probably to use (or create) a custom component which mimics the behavior of a `<select>` using other HTML elements.  The framework you're using (React) likely has many available 3rd party components for this.

Answer (score 1):

```css
select {
  background: yellow    
}
option {
  color: red 
}
```

```html
<select className="option-select">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: works on Chrome, not firefox

Comment: You can't style this on Firefox

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to style the select menu 'button', but not the dropdown itself. To accomplish that you need to mimic the functionality with javascript. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp

Answer (score 0):

Just a few CSS properties can change dropdown appearance and it's better to use a react components library such as [material-ui](https://mui.com/components/selects/).